# Is there a way to 'cancel' or stop an Interstital ad if the app is not in foreground?

Tags: android, admob

I have an interstitial ad implemented in my app. This ad is shown when a user performs a certain task. Now this task is on the main screen of my app, so the user just performs the task and leaves the app. The problem is, sometimes the ad is shown after the user performs the task and leaves the app. Will this get me banned from play store? Also, my main question, is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I think you will need to provide more infos. What do you mean with `this task is on the main screen` which task and how does it look like. A picture with a good description would make everything more clear!

Comment: @Mike I mean that it's on the first screen of the app. When you launch the app, that's the first thing you see. So a user performs the task and 'exits'. This happens fast. So sometimes the ad is shown after the user leaves the app.

Comment: I also have ads in my app and sometimes they are also shown for a really short time. But they are never displayed beyond `onPause` of my activity.. So maybe the problem is somewhere else..

Comment: If they're not shown beyond onPause, you mean to say if a new activity opens up and hence onPause is called,you just let the ad pass?

Comment: I mean when someone put my app to back or opens a third party app .. OnPause of the activity which includes the ad is called.. i have size `banner`. After onPause is called the ad is gone. This is logically, because the ad is nothing more like a custom view and should behave like all the other views in my activities layout...

Comment: Ah. You have a banner, so it's not much of a problem for you, since the banner stays attached to your app's view. It's interstitial in my case.

Comment: Ah sorry missed that detail!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your problem is that that are calling `interstitial.show()` from `onAdLoaded()` of your AdListener. Do **NOT** do this. It provides a poor user expereince and *will* get your account banned.

Instead you should call `interstitial.show()` from a natural break point in your app.

Answer (score -1):

uhmm i think this falls on workarounds, so what i am thinking, hope you know how to check if your app is showing or not using the lifecycle methods.. so suppose my boolean is

```
static boolean showing = false;
```

then on my interestial ad i add a listener

```
interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onAdClosed();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onAdLoaded();
                    if(Myclassname.showing){// check if your app is showing                    
                    interstitial.show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdOpened() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onAdOpened();
                }
            });
```

hope its good

Comment: I've already thought of that. But I have multiple activities. What if the user navigates to a different activity? The ad won't show then, because I'll have showing set to false because of onPause being called. I have this workaround as a last resort though.

Comment: this might sound foolish, but, idk, create respective booleans for each activity and check for if one is true using `&&` in the if statement **OR** (the sensible one) you could loop through running processes using the `activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();` and check if your process is running, then you continue..  if you do not know how to do that, you could search here on stackoverflow, there are tons of eg@user4351462